# Detect OS version - Windows Phone 7 or Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have an application for Windows Phone 7. I have created visual studio 2012 in windows 8 desktop. I am trying to use the application in Windows Phone 8 device also with some changes involved. How can I programmatically detect whether the device is Windows Phone 7 or Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just as you would on any other platform with C#: `Environment.OSVersion`

Comment: Environment.OSVersion gives me "Microsoft Windows NT 8.0.9903.0" whether this is the Windows 8 OS or Windows phone 8 device?

Comment: If you application is written for Windows PHONE, then it won't be installed into Windows 8 OS.

Comment: It could be PCL like my project

Answer (score 5):

You can use this toolkit to check the version of the phone:
http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/

> bool IsWP8() : Returns if the phone running the application is a
>   Windows Phone 8

EDIT: If you don't want to use the whole toolkit here is how it checks it:

```
public static bool IsWP8 { get { return Environment.OSVersion.Version >= TargetedVersion; } }

    private static Version TargetedVersion = new Version(8, 0);
```

Creds to original author.

Comment: This code is wrong as soon as desktop Windows is released with internal version number of 8

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to.

Either it is a Windows Phone 7 app and will work on both Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 devices or it is a Windows Phone 8 application.

A Windows Phone 7 app running on Windows Phone 8 shouldn't be able to do anything that a Windows Phone 7 device shouldn't be able to do.

Comment: Exactly, instead of checking on which platform you are running, check for each feature individually. Similar to how modernizr checks for features.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do it programmatically?

Comment: In fact I have created this app using vs2012 installed in Windows 8 desktop OS. the app is running in emulator. I want to detect whether the app is running under Windows phone 7 or Windows phone 8

Comment: Not really. FM Radio API is available in WP7 but not in WP8. Platform identification is inevitable

Comment: @sharmila - More information how what language is being used.  WP8 supports languages that WP7 does not.

Comment: I disagree: I need to link to the online documentation on how to change keyboard language. There's a specific page for WP7, and another one for WP8.

Comment: Well, disagree with "you should not do that". MediaHistoryItem.ImageStream has max size 16384 on WP7 and 76800 on WP8. How would you check for that feature?

Comment: @Alex - In that case, you would check the `MediaHistoryItem.MaxImageSize` property rather than checking the OS.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Thanks, I missed this property. Will check it when I'm back to the PC

Answer (score 0):

This article has some good strategies as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202996(v=vs.105).aspx

It is not just about run-time either, for example, your code may function one way on wp7 and another on wp8 depending on availability of an API.  In this case a #define may the best way to go, because you really don't care what kind of device you are running on, but what SDK you were built against.