# WP7.1 app on WP8 Device/Emulator - 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

My app (Silverlight & C#) built for WP7.1 works fine on 7.1 devices but not on WP8 devices, and due to this reason the app was removed from the Marketplace (the app was there in Marketplace and used by many users until the WP8 release).

I tried debugging the issue in the Emulator. I ran the 7.1 version of the app in WP8 emulator. In one of the lines of code I am converting a string to double as

```
double osVer = Convert.ToDouble("8.0.9903");
```

This line throws

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

I have no clue what `mscorlib.ni.dll` is and how to proceed further. Does anyone have any ideas? **Note:** The app works fine on WP7.1.

Comment: Perhaps you can simply use `IsWP8` method [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13303187/863980).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In one of the lines of code I am converting a string to double as " double osVer = Convert.ToDouble("8.0.9903");".

8.0.9903 isn't a valid double as it has two decimal points.

**UPDATE**:
Both WP7 and WP8 will throw an exception if this is seen, so it looks like your app on WP8 is getting a different format of string from somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToDouble` will use the current culture. So if the application is executed with a culture who has a difference decimal separator, a FormatException will be thrown.

On most cases, you'll want to explicitly provide a culture when calling `Convert.ToDouble`:

```
Convert.ToDouble("8.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Tried Convert.ToDuble("8.0.9903", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);. But it is throwing the same exception.